# how to efficiently convert numpy.array full of 14 bit binary numbers into corresponding two's complement in python?

Tags: python, numpy, twos-complement

having more than a million numbers stored in np.array. These are straight binary codes and I need to convert them into appropriate two's complement.

I'm using actually map of a converting function to each element of the array, but it is veeeery slow!

So, having e.g:

```
np.array((127,126,2,1,0,255,254,130,129,128))
```

I'd like to do some manipulation to get array containing

(127,126,2,1,0,-1,-2,-126,-127,-128)

Any hint appreciated
.d.

Comment: Those would have to be 8-bit numbers to get those results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to store the 14-bit numbers in an uint16 or int16, as appropriate, then shift 2 places to the left to capture the sign bit, view as the opposite data type and shift 2 places to the right, i.e.,
`data_out = numpy.uint16(data_in<<2).astype(numpy.int16)>>2`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Chad Gipson! I recommend you to review this [format guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) in which you can learn how to use inline code syntax for your answers and your own questions.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> a = numpy.array((127,126,2,1,0,255,254,130,129,128), dtype=numpy.uint8)
>>> a
array([127, 126,   2,   1,   0, 255, 254, 130, 129, 128], dtype=uint8)
>>> a.astype(numpy.int8)
array([ 127,  126,    2,    1,    0,   -1,   -2, -126, -127, -128], dtype=int8)

>>> a = numpy.array((127,126,2,1,0,255,254,130,129,128), dtype=numpy.uint16)
>>> a
array([127, 126,   2,   1,   0, 255, 254, 130, 129, 128], dtype=uint16)
>>> a.astype(numpy.int8)
array([ 127,  126,    2,    1,    0,   -1,   -2, -126, -127, -128], dtype=int8)
```

Comment: You could also use `a.view(np.int8)` to get a *view* of the same block of memory interpreted as signed integers.

Comment: ... assuming `a` has dtype `np.uint8`, that is.

Comment: How do you deal it when it is not 8 bit number vector but 14bit?

Comment: @DavidBelohrad: The code in the question shows 8-bit operation. Are you saying that you should have shown 14-bit operation?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for that mismatch.  I had an impression that the solution might be independent of the bit width so for the sake of simplicity I was talking about 8 bits.  The data I get are 14bit from a 1 gsps adc

Comment: Is there any chance you can get the data left-justified in a 16-bit datatype?

Comment: No chance. This goes directly from hardware. I might recompile the hardware part but this represents a considerable effort. I guess in case of 16bit number the recipe would be the same as for 8 bit

Comment: Well, that gets filed under "RevB", assuming you need realtime. Let me do a bit of research then...